# Match operators with similar start sequence

Tags: java, regex, text-processing

Imagine that I have a Java matching algoritm that wants to Match one of theses expressions:

```
key =  value
key => value
```

How can I build a Java Regex to match any `key-value` expression with the `=` character and ignore `=>` sequence?

For now I have the expression

```
([^=]+)\s*=\s*([^\r\n]+)\s*\r?\n?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yuo can split using a negative lookahead:

```
s.split("\\s*=(?!>)\\s*")
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zT3yE8/1) and [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/J5fJuy):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("abc = cde".split("\\s*=(?!>)\\s*")));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("abc => cde".split("\\s*=(?!>)\\s*")));
```

Results:

```
[abc, cde]
[abc => cde]
```

The `(?!>)` look-ahead fails the match of `>` follows `=`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! For escape the `=` I should user `(?<!\)`? As `s.split("\\s*(?<!\)=(?!>)\\s*")`

Comment: No idea what you mean. You do not need to escape `=`. Do you want to not match `something )= something else`?

Comment: For example, to create a regex thats accepts `\=` as key.